# NodeJs Middleware does not working properly to avoid duplication of data submission

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I've written a middleware to avoid duplication of submission of the same data. It seems like it's preventing duplication but it doesn't submit new data. I get the error "Can't set the headers after they are sent". Is there is any method that I can use to prevent this?

**Middleware**

```
function checkDuplication(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) { // is user logged in?

    User.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundUser) {
      if (err) {
        res.redirect('back');
        console.log(err);
      } else {

        for (var index = 0; index < foundUser.friendRequest.length; index++) {
          if ((foundUser.friendRequest[index].id.toString()) ===
            (req.user._id.toString())) {
            console.log("you are already in his friends list ");
            break;
          } else { //so is there is any way that I can only run this line 
            //once outside the loop and avoid several response by express

            console.log("one friend added");
            next();
          }
        }
        res.redirect("back");
      }
    })
  } else {
    res.redirect('back');
  }
}

//Post route to submit a data
router.post("/people/friendRequest/:id", checkDuplication,
  function(req, res) {

    User.findById(req.params.id, function(err, user) {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      } else {
        var Request = {
          id: req.user._id,
          username: req.user.username
        }

        user.friendRequest.push(Request);
        user.save();

        res.redirect("back"); //getting error due this line
      }
    })
    res.redirect("back");
})
```

Comment: Can't set the headers after they are send means you would have somewhere send back two time response back `res.redirect("back")` or callback . see your whole workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an array function, to check if any items match your criteria:

```
if (foundUser.friendRequest.some((fr) => fr.id.toString() === req.user._id.toString())) {
    console.log("you are already in his friends list ");
    res.redirect("back");
} else {
    next();
}
```

This will look through the array until it finds a match, at which point it will call `res.redirect("back").

If it finds no matches, it will call `next()`